# TabPane behaving weirdly. Not constraining contents

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Everytime my UI updates it gradually escapes out of the TabPane bounds. The Tab contains a BorderPane.

Any idea how this would happen legitimately? Is it a bug? Gif to illustrate problem.

[image: TabPane contents growing out of bounds]

Comment: This usually is because some size property is bound without taking insets into account. We cannot figure out which one without code though...

Comment: Or, what could also be a nice one is added the border width upon selecting. But again, cannot be sure without code

Comment: Even weirder. The same graph and table are used on another tab (I remove and relocated them on tab switching) but this doesn't happen on that tab. I've just compared their layout properties in scene builder and they are structured the same. I haven't programatically bound any size properties either. I'm not sure I could create an example that reproduces this.

Comment: I've found one difference between the two tabs. The graph goes into a StackPane on both tabs. The problematic tab had "use computed size" for pref size on the StackPane, the other tab had 200x150 as pref size. When I changed it to 200x150 on the probematic tab it stops happening. So the issue is with StackPane growing when not given a specific preferred size.